# How to check which user is logged in with Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am currently working on a website, and I wanted to know how do I check which user is logged in. Just to clarify I am using the Django built in models `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` to do my `login, logout etc.` What I don't know how to do is check which user is logged in, I know the method

```
if user.is_authenticated:
    # Other code goes here
```

But this method only checks weather the user is logged in not which user is logged in?

Comment: `request.user` is the logged in user.

Comment: Crude method: You could get all the users and loop throught them, removing the users who are not logged in:
 `users=User.objects.filter(active=True)
 for user in users:users.exclude(pk=user.pk) if user.is_authenticated()==False else pass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find info about the logged user in the request.user method

Here an example if you want to know the username:

```
username = request.user.username
```

Comment: Thank you soo much this was the solution to my problem

Answer (score 1):

If you make use of the [**`AuthenticationMiddleware`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/middleware/#module-django.contrib.auth.middleware) (this is the default if you create a new project), then this middleware will add a [**`.user`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) to the request. This is a lazy loaded user model object, or the [**`AnonymousUser`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser) if the user has not logged in.

But if tyhe user thus has logged in, this is a user model *object* just like any other. You thus can access fields, methods, etc. from that object, and use it when you create an object to let a `ForeignKey` refer to that user.

If you for example use the default [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model), then you can access attributes like `request.user.first_name`, `request.user.last_name`, `request.user.username`, etc.